# SessionStorage in backbone doesn't work before refresh page

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, session-storage

I'm working on a backbone application right now and I've a problem with sessionStorage values I think. If you think there's something else that's wrong just tell me!

When I run this script:

```
    <script>
      console.log((sessionStorage.appRole == "1" || sessionStorage.appRole == "2"));
    </script>
```

Then the outcome in the console is true.

But when the value is used to the template in my backbone using underscorejs the value inside of the IF statement aint rendered. But when I refresh my page then the button is visible. I wonder why it doesn't work the first time I visit the page. The value is correct but it's not being rendered.

```
    <% if (sessionStorage.appRole == "1" || sessionStorage.appRole == "2") { %>
      <button id="create" class="btn btn-primary"><%= i18n.create_user %></button>
    <% } %>
```

Do you have any ideas? I've scratched my head for hours and now I beg for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should fetch the values and store it to a variable and then pass it to the template.
Since template is seeking for a value to be in that variable it is failing.

```
var appRole = sessionStorage.appRole;
var user = i18n.create_user;
```

Pass the appRole,user values to the template

```
$(this.el).html(this.myTemplate({"appRole": appRole,"userDetail":user }));
```

Inside template fetch it like

```
<% if (appRole == "1" || appRole == "2") { %>
<button id="create" class="btn btn-primary"><%= userDetail %></button>
<% } %>
```

For myTemplate ,Include your template in view and assign it using the underscore template function.

```
myTemplate : _template(sampleTemplate),
```

And use the this.myTemplate(mymodelobj.toJSON()); where ever you need.

Look at the sample view file

```
define([
     'jquery',
     'underscore',
     'backbone',
     // Using the Require.js text! plugin, we are loaded raw text
     // which will be used as our views primary template
     'text!templates/project/list.html'
   ], function($, _, Backbone, projectListTemplate){
  var ProjectListView = Backbone.View.extend({
      el: $('#container'),
      render: function(){
              // Using Underscore we can compile our template with data
      var data = {};//json data
      var compiledTemplate = _.template( projectListTemplate, data );
      // Append our compiled template to this Views "el"
      this.$el.append( compiledTemplate );
   }
});
```

// Our module now returns our view
  return ProjectListView;
});

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I will try this out @ work tomorrow. And reply with the result. :)

Comment: I got an error with: 
Uncaught TypeError: string is not a function

        $(this.el).html(this.template({
          'appRole': sessionStorage.appRole
        }));

The error is targeting the template function as a string and not a function.

Comment: Please check with the initialization of the template

Comment: I'm sorry im not a backbone master. the thing you talk about is it:
`({
    template: _.template(UsersTemplate)
});`

Or is the initiation somewhere else in the view?

Comment: Yes exactly the same.I have updated the answer .Please verify.

Comment: This is how it looks right now: `template: _.template UsersTemplate`

`UsersTemplate = require 'text!templates/users.html'`

Inside that templates is where I've the if statement. I wonder where I should pass a json object to the template. When I tried to do that in the render function i got the error `Uncaught TypeError: string is not a function.

Comment: Please make sure your underscore is loaded and it should be in the following manner _ = require('underscore.js'); UsersTemplate = require('text!templates/users.html'); var template = _.template(UsersTemplate) and use it like template({"appRole": appRole,"userDetail":user });

Comment: Thanks alot mate. I think it works right now!

I'll check with my team and test it around abit but this might be the solution!